# jquery url prefacing and indexing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, indexing

I am using a CMS that is built into my hosting service. I really like it but I have run into a problem with indexing of pages. There is a store with categories but when I go to the individual categories they are not sending a specific URL to that category and the URL is showing up as the default URL for the store, the code uses ajax and jQuery also another lib sizzle.

Is there a way to override the showURL: false written into one of the libs so I can have the categories indexed with a code I can put into the HTML of the store page itself?

I've tried using `url.com/section?categoryId=category` but it is still sending me to a combination of all categories and not sending me to a category. The categories seem to be being created when the page loads so no URL is being printed for that category. no URL is being printed in the browser for each individual category. Every `?` I add to the url of the page is returning to the main page, no query seems to be working. I want to create direct links to each category, how would I go about doing this?

```
<section class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729789" element-type="SectionElement">
    <div class="element-children-container">
        <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729795" element-type="StoreCategoriesContainer">
            <div class="element-children-container">
                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729799" element-type="StoreFilters"></div>
                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729801" element-type="StoreSortingFilter"></div>
                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729797" element-type="line"></div>
                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729798" element-type="StoreCategoriesBreadcrumb"></div>
                <div class="site-element" element-id="id1517449729800" element-type="StoreSelectedFilters"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard to debug a verbal description of your code ;) Can you please edit your question and add the relevant code snippets (not just a one-liner, but all the relevant context) so we can have a go at understanding how the code works and then at suggesting a solution :)

Comment: Ok apparently the website is using breadcrumb pagination, is there anyway to link to an individual page in the breadcrumb pagination? there is no href only class and id. The problem I am having is the .js code being generated is so large the code itself is almost 3mb so its hard to find the actual issue within the code

Comment: Can you inspect the links on each category? (or are they fully js generated?) Note: I am totally stabbing in the dark as i have no code to look at :P

Comment: They are fully js generated so they are not cached and I can't make direct links to them and I need to

Comment: I am adding some code of where I think the problem may be in OP

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, there's really not enough for me to go on... :(